# ImageView, thumbnail and performances

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext, android-imageview

I have an activity in which I have an EditText, an ImageButton to grab an image, and an ImageView.

The ImageView is empty, but I can add a src via `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`
The EditText was very slow if I had an image too, so I'm using thumbnails now:

```
Bitmap thumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()),
            uploadedImageView.getWidth(), uploadedImageView.getWidth());
    uploadedImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbImage);
```

And all works fine now.

The problem is when I share an image with this activity from another app.
The EditText is slow as before the thumbnails.
This is how I'm doing it now:

in my onCreate method:

```
 if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            ...
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            ViewTreeObserver viewTree = uploadedImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
            viewTree.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                    imageFile = new File(FileUtils.getPath(MyActivity.this, selectedImageUri));

                    Bitmap thumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()),uploadedImageView.getWidth(),uploadedImageView.getWidth());
                    uploadedImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbImage);

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe onPreDraw() is being called several times? Print a log there to see how often.

Comment: Yes, you are right :/  is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Removing the OnpreDrawListener solved my problem. Thank you :)